# Google Cloud Functions deploy issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, jwt, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Cloud Functions can't be deployed of some weird googleapis npm module error, was using official google docs for migrate FCM legacy to V1.

Here is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node-cron": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.42",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron-parser": "^2.7.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "googleapis": "^40.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  }
```

and content of main function that causing the issue:

```js
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const key = require('./service-account.json');
        const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'];

        const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            key.client_email,
            undefined,
            key.private_key,
            SCOPES
        );

jwtClient.authorize(function(err: any, tokens: any) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(tokens.access_token);
        });
    });
```

Given console problem that is blocking deployment:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/googleapis.js:93
    async discoverAsync(url) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js:19:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/lib/index.js:16:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of your package.json.

Comment: What version of JavaScript / Node.js are you asking the function to run as?

Comment: @Kolban hmm it may be the issue then, there is Node 6 installed on Cloud Functions

Answer (score 3):

The issue was caused by old version of Node in Cloud Functions, update to 8 resolved error.